# how to activate click event in a dom element (Angular 2)

Tags: javascript, angular, dom

I need to load a component at loading

```
<app-main id="tasks" [(ngModel)]="tasks"></app-main>
```

And the call from js

```
public tasks;
ngOnInit() {
    this.tasks.click();
}
```

I have tryed `document.getElementById("tasks").click()` and `ngAfterViewInit()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To click the element, you can do the following:

> Change your html to following:

```
<app-main id="tasks" #tasks></app-main>
```

> ... then in your component class:

```
import { Component, ElementRef, ViewChild, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';
//...
@ViewChild('tasks') tasks:ElementRef;

ngAfterViewInit () {
    // Fire the click event of tasks
    this.tasks.nativeElement.click();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but it give "ERROR TypeError: this.tasks is undefined". I'll continue search for another problems that can cause it

Comment: yes that is correct behavior. The click method should be called after the view has been initialized. I have updated the answer.

Comment: it continue failing, I include ElementRef in the constructor and it continues failing

Comment: where have you defined `@ViewChild('tasks') tasks:ElementRef;` in your class ?

Comment: create a plunker link with your code please, or add your component class code in the question

Comment: I change machine and start to works, i´ll send it to check. thanks for all ;)